# Grails log4j SMTPAppender NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: grails, dependency-management

How do I configure SMTPAppender in a new Grails 2.4.5 project?  I receive a NoClassDefFoundError when running in the development environment:

> | Error log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: javax/mail/Message
>
> | Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Message

[Gist: Detailed stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/jamesallman/9dc36dcc3f46874c735b)

I have configured a dependency for javax.mail and configured log4j as follows:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
}

log4j = {
    appenders {
        appender new org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender(
            name: 'smtp',
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c %M %x%n%p: %m%n')
            to: 'example@example.com',
            from: 'example@example.com',
            subject: 'Grails Message',
            SMTPHost: '127.0.0.1')
        )
    }
}
```

[GitHub: Example Project](https://github.com/jamesallman/test-log4j-smtpappender)

Comment: Anybody found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but I struggled with the same till I found a solution that is at least working for me (not with SMTPAppender but with Sentry - same purpose).

The explanation I found with the errors you where receiving

> Error log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: javax/mail/Message
>
> Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Message

Come from this piece of code:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
}
```

The thing is that when you compile things work, when you try to do `grails run-app` you receive this error.

The explanation I found is that the log4j initializes before the maven dependency is resolved.

I wrote a comment of how I've used Sentry as an appender.
https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/issues/184#issuecomment-259432057

Basically, instead of adding the maven dependency I've downloaded the java file, and added it to the grails project in src/java

So for Sentry por example I added the SentryAppender.java to my.package.sentry so then in log4j I added:

```
  appenders {
    environments {
        // This block is set up to use the stock raven SentryAppender in
        // production. Sentry Appender runs into all kinds of
        // class loading weirdness when used in a forked grails environment
        production {
            appender new my.package.sentry.SentryAppender(
                name: 'sentry',
                dsn: 'REDACTED',                
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN
            )
        }

        // Uncomment this block if you need to test sentry
        // in a dev environment
        development {
            appender new my.package.sentry.SentryAppender(
                name: 'sentry',
                dsn: 'REDACTED',                
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN
            )
        }
    }    

  }

  root {
    warn 'stdout', 'sentry'
    error 'stdout', 'sentry'
    additivity = false
  }
```

in that way, it does not depend on an external dependency.

I guess that you could do something similar to the mail dependency and add the java files to the src folder.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

That looks weird - are you combining the dependencies block and the `log4j` block here unintenionally, or are they in the same file in your app? The dependency should be in `BuildConfig.groovy` and the `log4j` block should be in `Config.groovy`. Also, it shouldn't be `log4j {` but rather `log4j = {`.

This is likely a timing issue. If `Config.groovy` is parsed before the Javamail dependency is resolved, it will fail. Try commenting out the parts that reference the Javamail classes and run `grails clean` and `grails compile`. That will resolve dependencies and add that jar to the classpath. Then you can uncomment that code and run `grails compile` again.

Comment: The `log4j = {` was a transcription error.  These settings were copied from an older working project.    I tested with OpenJDK 1.7.0_79 and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45.  I have added a link to a clean example exhibiting this issue.

Comment: I downloaded your GitHub app and did what I suggested in my answer (I commented out the `appenders` and `root` blocks, compiled, then uncommented them and compiled again) and it worked fine.

Comment: I just did the process again, using IDEA 14.1.3 and directly using the grails CLI from a terminal and I am getting the exact same error.

Comment: In Grails 2.4.5 it should be `log4j.main = {`. It used to be `log4j = {` in earlier versions. Maybe that still works, but at least `grails create-app` now generates `log4j.main = {`